# How can be located image in the middle of his div, if image is variable and can be bigger then his div wrapper or smaller?

Tags: css

How can be  image center horizontally inside smaller or bigger div, (image is variable and can be bigger then his div wrapper or smaller)?

Exist Javascript solution, but i looking for css solution.

The sample code that not working: (html should be not changed only css)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>my test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper" style="width:300px;margin:0 auto;">
            <div id="image_content" style="margin:0 auto;">
                <img src="image_small_then_300_or_bigger.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527811/css-vertical-centering?

Comment: the OP said "center horizontally", not vertical.

Answer (score 1):

You want to center align the `image_content` within the `wrapper`?

### text-align

`<div id="wrapper" style="width:300px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">`

### background-image

`<div id="wrapper" style="width:300px;margin:0 auto;background:transparent url('image_small_then_300_or_bigger.jpg') 50% 50%;">` *good call @gov*

Comment: if text-align:center doesn't work use margin left or padding left and make it in the center.

Comment: otherwise you can make div as background image and give background position as center center

Comment: 1. Its not possible to solve with margin left without javascript 2. I dont want use background because the image will not exist for google