# What is a straightforward solution to vertically centering on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I've seen a lot of discussion and debate on this with solutions from pure CSS to pure HTML. They can get pretty complicated, nesting divs within divs, using some pretty intense looking CSS. I figured I'd ask though, because I need a straightforward solution to this problem, and it needs to not rely on CSS tables (i.e. {display:table;} because I'm using that to show/hide the entire div and solutions using that never seem to work nicely with my other code. So how should I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css vertical centering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527811/css-vertical-centering)

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the discussions and debates I was talking about. I spent a while there trying to find something to make my code work and it didn't happen, so here I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
  table.center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  h1.center {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<div id="hide-able">
  <table class="center">
    <tr><td><h1 class="center">I'm centered!</h1></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I'm more of a "get things done" type of guy as opposed to a "purest" type.  If a table works, then go for it.  Quite frankly I'd rather stuff the odd table here and there instead of doing mind gymnastics trying to force a "div/css" solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can have your outer div `#wrapper{margin:0 auto;width:900px}`

that gets it done nicely.
make sure to include doc-type for IE.

Comment: yea. try this though <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



<style type="text/css"> #wrapper{margin:0 auto;width:200px;border:2px solid red;} </style> 

<body>
<div id="wrapper"> <h1 class="center">I'm centered!</h1> </div>

<body>

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the content to be centered horizontally rather than vertically?