# Is there a way to use CSS attribute as value?

Tags: css

I mean, is there a way to do something like:

```
width: 92%;
left: (100-width)/2;
```

so I can change the width without care with the "left"?

***obs**. I don't want to know about other ways of doing this centering, like with magins=auto, I just want to know if I can use an css attribute as a value to other attribute. Thanks! :)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in pure CSS, no.

CSS precompilers like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) offer it, though.

Comment: LESS looks incredible! It adds all the features CSS as a language misses so dearly! +1 for the reference :-)

Comment: +1 thanks! The doubt now is: [can I use it with xul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411973/can-i-use-less-with-xul)?

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure I understand? LESS is a *pre*-processor, you will have to run a small program on the style sheets before you can use them. The end result is normal CSS that should work everywhere

Comment: Ah, ok.. so, with this 2 lines of code from my example, saving a file as test.less and running it with command line `less test.less` it just opens, as if was vim editor opening the file.. I'm reading about how to it..

Comment: the [docs](http://lesscss.org/docs) talk about `lessc`, but I found just `less` with ubuntu's apt-get...

Comment: "`less`" is another thing, a text pager from UNIX systems. Probably the reason why the CSS compiler was specifically named `lessc` was to avoid the name clash.

Answer (score 3):

Currently no, although, [css calculations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) seem to allow for the possibility of this, albeit at a later date.

It might be worth reading this pre-existing question: [Value calculation for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css)

Comment: @Tom, yeah; I'm excited by the possibilities too! =)

Comment: Interesting! Hadn't heard of these. +1

Comment: @Pekka, don't they sound fun? =) I'm almost terrified at the prospect of dealing with the browser implementation, though... =/

Comment: yeah, they sound interesting! Although it will surely take a few years until we can even think about using them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way unless you are generating the css itself dynamically, [with this for instance](http://sass-lang.com/)

Also some browsers have some support for [css variables](http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=css+variables&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), but you can't do math on them as AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: No

EDIT:

You could do it from JavaScript using DOM like:

`object.style.left = (100 - object.style.width) / 2`

But, you would have to call this code, every now and then, and I don't think that's what you intended.