# Can I use LESS with Xul?

Tags: xul, less

Can I use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) with Xul?
Does anyone already used them together?

Comment: LESS Xul ... sounds like a great premise for Ghostbusters 3.

Comment: So it's not less [http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/ ]

Comment: @user502515 No, it's less [http://lesscss.org/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anyone use it, but nothing stops you from trying. LESS is just a preprocessor, which outputs CSS files, so the kind of problems you could expect to find should be with Mozilla-specific CSS constructs, that you might need to use. I bet any such problems would not be very hard to fix.

On the other hand, unless you're working on something as complex as writing a theme from scratch, I wouldn't expect LESS to provide enough benefits to justify the additional development step.

Comment: I stay with the second part of the answer. I'm not working in a so complex system.