# CSS calculate "function"

Tags: html

I know there is a "function" to calculate e.g. percentage values plus pixel values.

The syntax lookes something like this:

```
#somelement {
Height: calculate ( 50% + 20px);
}
```

Please tell me this function is real, and not just a web designer dream....

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: ok I am thinking no... and even if it is in the specifications of the new html5 standards I am almost sure that no browser at this moment supports that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS 3 includes the calc() function: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc.

This is a good tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is the CSS3 `calc`.  It is not widely supported, however.

[W3C Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)

[MDN Documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc)