# Is there a way to add and subtract values in CSS?

Tags: css, height, margin

I have a div that I am positioning with a negative margin, but I'd like it to extend all the way down to the bottom of its container div so I can use a border that doesn't just end randomly. If you look at http://kineticaid.com/k/home.php you will understand what I mean. I can't just extend its height in pixels because the container div's height changes dynamically with pages. What I want to do is something like this:

```
#rightcol {
float: right;
width: 225px;

height: 100% + 250px;

margin: -325px -25px 0 0;
}
```

Basically I'm asking if you can add and subtract in CSS. Thanks!

Comment: There are CSS preprocessors like LESS or SASS that add such feature, but I'm not really sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I think I'm just looking for a way to combine pixels and percentage in the same CSS statement, if it's even possible.

Comment: Check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css

May be you can use Javascript...

Answer (score 35):

Yes. CSS3 has the `calc()` function. This works in the current versions of most browsers (http://caniuse.com/calc).

```css
height: calc( 100% + 250px );
```

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

HTML:

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}

#one {
    width: calc(50% + 20px);
}

#two {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. It's good to know that this kind of thing has been included in CSS3.

Comment: there is also a webkit vendor prefix

Comment: This post is ancient but I came across it looking for a way to add values for a different reason in CSS. QUESTION: if you set margins or padding via calc(), will that be re-calculated automatically if the screen changes? Like if you rotate your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Sass and less have similar such features too what you need, but I think what your asking for would have to be done with javascript or jquery to do your calculations.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is ["Faux Columns"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), but you need to change your layout a bit for this.

Comment: This is good but it would require using Photoshop which is not really up my alley :p

Comment: Just because a skill isn't "up your alley" doesn't stop it being a good solution. Basic image editing is quite a core web developer skill

Comment: Well it's also not what I was asking. I was wondering if CSS has any built-in capability to add and subtract values of different types. It is a good solution though.

Comment: Well u ask for http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc. But this is the wrong approach.