# margin-left based on the size of the current element

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the percentage in margin-left a percentage of the image size instead of the containing element? [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8MP73/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been asked in this link: [Value calculation for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css)

To my knowledge, as well, CSS is not a language with the ability of complex interoperability between selectors or between property values of selectors.

So the best way you can choose might be using JavaScript or a JavaScript library such as jQuery, in order to find out what exactly a certain percentage of a certain property value corresponds to. Then you can dynamically assign that corresponding value to the property you intended to, using JS/jQuery of course.