# CSS - Use calc() to keep widths of elements the same

Tags: html, css, calc

Is something like this possible in CSS?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="elementOne">elementOne</td>
    <td id="elementtwo">elementtwo</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div style="width: calc(document.getElementById(elementOne).width)"></div>
```

So that the div is always the same width as `elementOne`.

Is there such a feature in CSS, using calc() or some other means?

Comment: No, there is not such feature (AFAIK something like that has been supported in IE **until** version 7) but you have an even more powerful feature: JavaScript.

Comment: This was called `expression()` in IE, and it was a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css#answer-528361

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not possible with CSS.

For that you will have to use JavaScript (`document.getElementById(elementOne).offsetWidth` or similar, depending on exactly what width you are looking for). Calc is [used](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to do math, not execute scripts. There is no way of putting JS in a CSS statement, like you are trying to do.

For more help on the JS bit, see [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Edit: For some background on why this would be a bad idea to implement in CSS, se [Value calculation for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527861/value-calculation-for-css#answer-528361) (TL;DR: It has been tried. Things exploded)

Answer (score 22):

Use CSS variables:

```
<style>
:root { --width: 100px; } /* Set the variable --width */

table td{
  width: var(--width);    /* use it to set the width of TD elements */
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab">elementOne</td>
    <td class="tab">elementtwo</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- reuse the variable to set the width of the DIV element -->
<div style="width: var(--width); border: 1px solid;">Element three</div>
```

You can also use variables in the calc() function:

```
<div style="width: calc(var(--width) * 3); border: 1px solid;">Element four</div>
```

Comment: Be warned, that CSS variables are not supported very well in IE and Edge (and many other smaller browsers); http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are 2 possible ways of doing this with CSS (although not with calc):

1) If you know how many columns you have, then just use % (i.e. 50% for 2 cols)

2) If you don't know how many columns you have or you maybe can't use % for whatever use-case you might have, then you can use [flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).
Depending on your browser compatibility target, you can combine the "old" and "new" syntax to get some awesome results.