# How to align content of a div to the bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Say I have the following CSS and HTML code:

```css
#header {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  Header content (one or multiple lines)
</div>
```

The header section is fixed height, but the header content may change.

I would like the content of the header to be vertically aligned to the bottom of the header section, so the last line of text "sticks" to the bottom of the header section.

So if there is only one line of text, it would be like:

```
-----------------------------
| Header title
|
|
|
| header content (resulting in one line)
-----------------------------
```

And if there were three lines:

```
-----------------------------
| Header title
|
| header content (which is so
| much stuff that it perfectly
| spans over three lines)
-----------------------------
```

How can this be done in CSS?

Answer (score 1534, accepted):

Relative+absolute positioning is your best bet:

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 150px;
}

#header-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#header, #header * {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 100, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div id="header-content">And in the last place, where this might not be the case, they would be of long standing, would have taken deep root, and would not easily be extirpated. The scheme of revising the constitution, in order to correct recent breaches of it, as well as for other purposes, has been actually tried in one of the States.</div>
</div>
```

But you may run into issues with that.  When I tried it I had problems with dropdown menus appearing below the content.  It's just not pretty.

Honestly, for vertical centering issues and, well, any vertical alignment issues with the items aren't fixed height, it's easier just to use tables.

Example: [Can you do this HTML layout without using tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522928/can-you-do-this-html-layout-without-using-tables)

Comment: I actually found that solution before asking here, but somehow forgot to add the position: relative; to the header div and the content kept landing at the bottom of the page. Thanks

Comment: You can manage your dropdown position with the z-index property to bring it to front. Remember that the z-index property works with elements positioned relatively or absolutely. Also, is not correct semantically speaking to use a table to achieve layout results.

Comment: In the case of text content as described in the original problem, #header-content should really be a `p` element, or at the very least a `span`

Comment: if `#header` has a fixed height, here is a quick hack: `#header-content { position: relative; bottom: -4px; }` (change the -4px to whatever value works for you), this is kinda dirty but has the advantage of letting `#header` keep its positioning (ie. static) if required. Otherwise, go for @Cletus solution.

Comment: This doesn't allow the content to scroll if the content is shorter than container.

Comment: also if you want to align to the center (like `text-align: center`) you can use : 
`left: 0; right: 0;` in addition to what Cletus said.

Comment: Don't use tables for non-tabular data!  Instead, use the CSS display properties `display: table-cell`, or `table-row`, or `table`.  You never again need to use tables for pure layout.

Comment: Header position is relative to what ?

Comment: This fails in react components; the right and modern way is the flexbox way.

Comment: I disagree with @Jeremy-DeerAngel-org and agree with the accepted answer, sometimes tables are the right choice. Don't sacrifice layout stability with the "don't use tables" ideology. Tables are usually not the right choice with our modern JS frameworks, but tables sometimes are the best approach for the layout.

Comment: Does not work when the content on the bottom has variable height, causes it to extend out of the container bounds.

Comment: Also add 'display: contents;' to '#header' so that it stretches to 100% height.

Answer (score 240):

If you're not worried about legacy browsers use a flexbox.

The parent element needs its display type set to flex

```css
div.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then you set the child element's align-self to flex-end.

```css
span.child {
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Here's the resource I used to learn:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @bafromca, two reasons that doesn't work. 1: Use 'align-self' instead of align-items (my fault, I've edited my original post). 2: 100% height won't work unless the parent has height.

Comment: Did not work for me, I want it at the bottom of the container, not the end of the items in the container.

Comment: In 2020 this should be the correct answer: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Awesome answer, the `flex-end` feature was just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah this is a preferable solution really. It may work differently in different browsers but seems that flexbox is almost always the way to go. Glad I found this.

Answer (score 202):

Use CSS positioning:

```css
/* Creates a new stacking context on the header */
#header {
  position: relative;
}

/* Positions header-content at the bottom of header's context */
#header-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

As [cletus noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css/585965#585965), you need identify the header-content to make this work.

```html
<span id="header-content">some header content</span>

<div style="height:100%; position:relative;">
    <div style="height:10%; position:absolute; bottom:0px;">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: fyi ... this caused my header-content to collapse its width, so I had to add a `width = '100%'` on the header-content

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd You could also fix that by adding display:block to #header-content.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd The reason is because `<span>` elements have `display: inline;` by default, which does not take up the full width of the container. The most appropriate fix would be to change the span to a `<div>`, which is a block element by default.

Comment: Or one of <h1> - <h6> which is also block by default and identifies the text as a header, which is useful to search engines, assistive technologies, and people reading the code.

Comment: Does not work when the content on the bottom has variable height, causes it to extend out of the container bounds.

Answer (score 147):

I use these properties and it works!

```css
#header {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Isn't supported in IE8 and earlier.  It IS supported in IE9.

Comment: @cale_b According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell) it *DOES* work in IE8.

Comment: @ZachL Happenstance - I'm supporting a legacy app in IE8 for a corporate client and this _does in fact_ work.

Comment: @fguillen: tested in Chrome (v31) just now as well.  Works there, too.

Comment: NOTE: `table-cell` will not allow you to use `min-height` (at least in Chrome 34). Sadly, that was a requirement for me, otherwise this'd be the exact solution I was looking for. (Still gets my upvote!)

Comment: `table-cell` breaks a lot of things. Like the Bootstrap grid system. `col-md-12` won't give you a 100% wide div anymore.

Comment: Doesn't work if content of #header has display: block.

Comment: @Gavin Hmm, it certanly didn't work for me and switching display of content changed it. Sadly I can't remember exact example. But yours stops working if I set `position: absolute` to #header. Would be nice if there were all the additional conditions required. Like position shouldn't be absolute.

Comment: @Atomosk yes, setting a `display: table-cell` element to `position: absolute` will have undesired consequences.

Comment: I like this - great for collapsing a row of divs with a header as the first element on a mobile.

Comment: This could be an issue if you want to use a flex box for your content.

Comment: Stop supporting IE8 already, we are moving forward not backward

Comment: 'display: contents;' for '#header' works better

Answer (score 70):

After struggling with this same issue for some time, I finally figured out a solution that meets all of my requirements:

- Does not require that I know the container's height.
- Unlike relative+absolute solutions, the content doesn't float in its own layer (i.e., it embeds normally in the container div).
- Works across browsers (IE8+).
- Simple to implement.

The solution just takes one `<div>`, which I call the "aligner":

**CSS**

```
.bottom_aligner {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 0px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="bottom_aligner"></div>
... Your content here ...
```

This trick works by creating a tall, skinny div, which pushes the text baseline to the bottom of the container.

Here is a complete example that achieves what the OP was asking for.  I've made the "bottom_aligner" thick and red for demonstration purposes only.

CSS:

```
.outer-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 175px;
  width: 300px;
}

.top-section {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50%;
}

.bottom-section {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 8px;
}

.bottom-aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 3px;
  background: red;
}

.bottom-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-content {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="top-section">
      This text
      <br> is on top.
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-section">
      <div class="bottom-aligner"></div>
      <div class="bottom-content">
        I like it here
        <br> at the bottom.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: Align bottom content]

Comment: Almost perfect :) but it doesn't allow automatic line breaks.

Comment: Doesn't work if outer-container can scroll (overflow-y: auto). :(

Comment: This also works if put in a `::before` rule, which removes the need of an extra element.  We used flex at the end, but this is useful when you can't.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. It works only if the `height` of the box/container _and_ its parents is set (to px or % or whatever).

Answer (score 56):

The modern way to do it would be using [**flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). See the example below. You don't even need to wrap `Some text...` into any HTML tag, since text directly contained in a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

```css
header {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;                   /* defines flexbox */
  flex-direction: column;          /* top to bottom */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* first item at start, last at end */
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  Some text aligns to the bottom
</header>
```

If there is only some text and you want to align vertically to the bottom of the container.

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;                   /* defines flexbox */
  align-items: flex-end;           /* bottom of the box */
}
```

```html
<section>Some text aligns to the bottom</section>
```

Comment: I needed my bottom-aligned element to still be present in the document flow, which isn't possible when using `position:absolute;`. This solution worked perfectly for my case!

Comment: Inside react components, this is the right solution. The accepted solution fails.

Comment: Works in react. And you can bottom-center the text with `justify-content: center;`.

Answer (score 34):

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

Comment: Note that flexbox is not [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in old browsers.

Comment: @AnthonyB - define old? We have to change this record as developers. Technology moves forward, and the old simply don't survive. IE9 and 10 have issues with flex from what I can see, but they were released in 2011 and 2012 respectively... it's 2017. We have to let go of these outdated and broken browsers. If not for visual satisfaction, but for security and general software updates.

Comment: @Tisch you're absolutely right we have to, as developers, use decent and recent technology. But I'd simply warn about this compatibility issue, in order to not to be surprised.

Comment: if the content under the `<h1>` is inside a `<p>` or `<div>` I would use `justify-content: space-between`.

Comment: The only answer to this question.

Answer (score 32):

I have encountered the problem several times and there are good solutions but also not so good ones. So you can achieve this in different ways with flexbox, with the grid system or display table. My preferred variant is a mix of flex and 'margin-bottom: auto'. Here is my personal collection of text-bottom possibilities:

#### 1. Flex / margin-top: auto;

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;
  display: flex;  
}  

.child {    
  margin-top: auto;
  background: red;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 2. Flex /  align-self: flex-end

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;
}

.child {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 3. Flex / align-items: flex-end;

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;
  display: flex;       
  align-items: flex-end; 
}  

.child {  
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 4. Grid / align-self: end;

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;  
  display: grid;  
}  

.child {  
  align-self: end;
  background: red;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 5. Table / vertical-align: bottom;

Personal I don't like this approach with table.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;  
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}  

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: red;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

### With spacer

#### 6. Flex; / flex: 1;

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}  

.spacer {
  flex: 1;    
}
.child {
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">  
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 7. Flex / flex-grow: 1;

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}  

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.child {  
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">  
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

#### 8. Inline-block / PseudoClass::before

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;  
  background: green;  
}

.child::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;  
}

.child {  
  height:200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bottom text</div>  
</div>
```

❤️ My personal preferred versions are:  1., 2. and 3.

Comment: Thank you! So much time and of course there was a simple solution (#1)

Answer (score 28):

Inline or inline-block elements can be aligned to the bottom of block level elements if the line-height of the parent/block element is greater than that of the inline element.*

markup:

```html
<h1 class="alignBtm"><span>I'm at the bottom</span></h1>
```

css:

```css
h1.alignBtm {
  line-height: 3em;
}
h1.alignBtm span {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

*make sure you're in standards mode

Answer (score 15):

You can simply achieved flex

```css
header {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;                   /* defines flexbox */
  flex-direction: column;          /* top to bottom */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* first item at start, last at end */
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  Some text aligns to the bottom
</header>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use following approach:

```css
.header-parent {
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
}

.header-content {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-parent">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  <div class="header-content">
    Header content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works best in the grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here is another solution using flexbox but without using **flex-end** for bottom alignment. The idea is to set `margin-bottom` on **h1** to **auto** to push the remaining content to the bottom:

```css
#header {
  height: 350px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:1px solid;
}

#header h1 {
 margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  Header content (one or multiple lines) Header content (one or multiple lines)Header content (one or multiple lines) Header content (one or multiple lines)
</div>
```

We can also do the same with `margin-top:auto` on the text but in this case we need to wrap it inside a `div` or `span`:

```css
#header {
  height: 350px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:1px solid;
}

#header span {
 margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  <span>Header content (one or multiple lines)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution so far! Because it supports `overflow-y: auto` (other solutions doesn't).

Comment: Great solution the margin-top: auto is inspired.

Answer (score 9):

The best possible solution to move a div to the bottom is as follows.
Basically what you need to do is to set display flex and flex-direction as a column to the parent and add a 'margin-top: auto' to its child which needs to be floated to the bottom of the container
Note: I have used bootstrap and its classes.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex; // added for representation purpose only. Bootstrap default class is already added
  flex-direction: column;
}

.link-02 {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box-wrapper d-flex flex-column col-4">
  <div>incidunt blanditiis debitis</div>
    <div class="news-box">
      <img class="d-block" alt="non ipsam nihil" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p>Labore consectetur doloribus qui ab et qui aut facere quos.</p>
    </div>
  <a href="https://oscar.com" target="_blank" class="link-02">
    This is moved to bottom with minimal effort
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple, dynamic height items, use the CSS display values of table and table-cell:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

  <div class="valign bottom">
    <div>

      <div>my bottom aligned div 1</div>
      <div>my bottom aligned div 2</div>
      <div>my bottom aligned div 3</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.valign {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.valign > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.valign.bottom > div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I've created a JSBin demo here: http://jsbin.com/INOnAkuF/2/edit

The demo also has an example how to vertically center align using the same technique.

Answer (score 7):

All these answers and none worked for me... I'm no flexbox expert, but this was reasonably easy to figure out, it is simple and easy to understand and use. To separate something from the rest of the content, insert an empty div and let it grow to fill the space.

https://jsfiddle.net/8sfeLmgd/1/

```css
.myContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.filler {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div>Top</div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

This reacts as expected when the bottom content is not fixed sized also when the container is not fixed sized.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need absolute+relative for this. It is very much possible using relative position for both container and data. This is how you do it.

Assume height of your data is going to be `x`. Your container is relative and footer is also relative. All you have to do is add to your data

```
bottom: -webkit-calc(-100% + x);
```

Your data will always be at the bottom of your container. Works even if you have container with dynamic height.

**HTML will be like this**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="data"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS will be like this**

```
.container{
  height:400px;
  width:600px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  display:block;
}
.data{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  position:relative;
   float:left;
  border:1px solid blue;
  bottom: -webkit-calc(-100% + 40px);
   bottom:calc(-100% + 40px);
}
```

[Live example here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/i6jrmpv2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain what `bottom: -webkit-calc(-100% + x);` is doing?

Comment: @mhatch it keeps footer at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the flexy way to do it. Of course, it's not supported by IE8, as the user needed 7 years ago. Depending on what you need to support, some of these can be done away with.

Still, it would be nice if there was a way to do this without an outer container, just have the text align itself within it's own self.

```
#header {
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

a very simple, one-line solution, is to add line-heigth to the div, having in mind that all the div's text will go bottom.

CSS:

```
#layer{width:198px;
       height:48px;
       line-height:72px;
       border:1px #000 solid}
#layer a{text-decoration:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="layer">
    <a href="#">text at div's bottom.</a>
</div>
```

keep in mind that this is a practical and fast solution when you just want text inside div to go down, if you need to combine images and stuff, you will have to code a bit more complex and responsive CSS

Answer (score 4):

*An addition to the other flex-box solutions mentioned:*

You can use `flex-grow: 1` on the first div. This way, your second div will be aligned to the bottom while the first will cover all remaining space.

On the parent div, you must use `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`.

[image]

```
/* parent-wrapper div */
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* first-upper div */
.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yj3ve05/

Answer (score 3):

if you could set the height of the wrapping div of the content (#header-content as shown in other's reply), instead of the entire #header, maybe you can also try this approach:

*HTML*

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <div id="header-content">
        <span>
            first line of header text<br>
            second line of header text<br>
            third, last line of header text
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#header-content{
    height:100px;
}

#header-content::before{
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

#header-content span{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[show on codepen](http://codepen.io/codeboyim/pen/pGxcs)

Answer (score 2):

I have devised a way which is a lot simpler than what's  been mentioned.

Set the height of the header div. Then inside that, style your `H1` tag as follows:

```
float: left;
padding: 90px 10px 11px
```

I'm working on a site for a client, and the design requires the text to be at the bottom of a certain div. I've achieved the result using these two lines, and it works fine. Also, if the text does expand, the padding will still remain the same.

Comment: Will cause content to float over other content when resizing screens using responsive layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution bassed on a default bootstrap start template

```
/* HTML */

<div class="content_wrapper">
  <div class="content_floating">
    <h2>HIS This is the header<br>
      In Two Rows</h2>
    <p>This is a description at the bottom too</p> 
  </div>
</div>

/* css */

.content_wrapper{
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
      min-height: 100%;
    }

.content_floating{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-bottom:80px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#header {
    height: 150px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.top{
    flex: 1;
}   

<div id="header">
    <h1 class="top">Header title</h1>
    Header content (one or multiple lines)
</div>
```

```css
#header {
    height: 250px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.top{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1 class="top">Header title</h1>
    Header content (one or multiple lines)
</div>
```

Comment: This causes resizing of the top div. Which works for basic text layouts, but does not work when things have backgrounds and colors and sizes to respect.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}

div{
  width:300px;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  color:#fff;
  height:150px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h4>Heading</h4>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<!-- <p> Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</p> -->
</div>
```

Just simply use `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` to make child sync in vertical order then apply `justify-content:space-between` to justify height of parent div with its children content. so that you can achieve your goal. Try this snippet to resolve issue.

I really appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
div.myclass { margin-top: 100%; }
```

try changing the % to fix it. Example: 120% or 90% ...etc.

Comment: Works perfectly fine with 1 set of content, but will need to be adjusted if the content changes. If it's dynamic content, then dont use this!

Answer (score 0):

The site I just did for a client requested that the footer text was a high box, with the text at the bottom I achieved this with simple padding, should work for all browsers.

```
<div id="footer">
  some text here
</div>
```

```
#footer {
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Your first declaration `padding: 0 30px` is a bit redundant, you may as well have put `padding: 30px` then the other 2 declarations.

Comment: Absolutely true, however I'm following the practices of my workplace.

Comment: Really?, that seems like plain *bad* practice. Just use the shorthand, or be explicit everywhere. `padding: 60px 30px 8px;`, `padding: 60px 30px 8px 30px;`, four explicit `padding-` rules, or even @TheWaxMann's suggestion are all superior - and I'm willing and able to argue that one ;-)

Answer (score -4):

A perfect cross-browser example is probably this one here:

http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/213/213.css&page=0

The idea is both to display the div at the bottom and also making it stick there. Often the simple approach will make the sticky div scroll up with the main content.

Following is a fully working minimal example. Note that there's no div embedding trickery required. The many BRs are just to force a scrollbar to appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #floater {
            background: yellow;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            z-index: 5;
            border-top: 2px solid gold;
        }

    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


    <div id="floater"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are wondering your code might not be working on IE, remember to add the DOCTYPE tag at the top. It's crucial for this to work on IE. Also, this should be the first tag and nothing should appear above it.

Comment: Since you're declaring your document as XHTML strict, you should also self-close your `<br />` tags...

Comment: @KarlKildén if you were referring to the comment from aaamos, it most definitely isn't a silly comment - serving the above document with its [correct `content-type` header](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/sep2003/) would result in the browser throwing an xml parsing error.

Comment: This is a bad practise! Use CSS instead!

Answer (score -4):

Seems to be working:

```
#content {
    /* or just insert a number with "px" if you're fighting CSS without lesscss.org :) */
    vertical-align: -@header_height + @content_height;

    /* only need it if your content is <div>,
     * if it is inline (e.g., <a>) will work without it */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Using [less](http://lesscss.org) makes solving CSS puzzles much more like coding than like... I just love CSS. It's a real pleasure when you can change the whole layout (without breaking it :) just by changing one parameter.

Answer (score -6):

2015 solution

```
<div style='width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid red;'>

    <table width=100% height=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
        <tr><td valign=bottom>{$This_text_at_bottom}</td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qERMdx

your welcome

Comment: Table layout for this can be problematic; CSS is recommended instead.  The valign property is also not supported in HTML5. (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp)

Comment: You got me with this trick.