# Should I use a table for this?

Tags: html, css

Unluckily I don't know what to do :(
[image: example]

I want to align the text "bla bla...." at the bottom of the left div.

Setting it as `position:absolute & bottom=0` doesnt work always because there are cases where image does not exist, and that would be a problem as if the text wont increase container div height...

I could change the layout if there is no `img` with php but that doesnt guarantee that in case `img` has less height than text, text overflow etc...

I know this is strange, the table is the only solution I have?

Comment: A previous Discussion on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table is rarely (if at all) a good solution for layout.

You could do a `min-height` so if the `img` does not exist, you will always have a height that will be adhered to.

Comment: Yes but i cant be sure of the textheight as it can be more than one line

Comment: @Parhs Well `min-height` allows the box to expand in height once over the threshold specified.

Comment: Maybe what Parhs means is resulting same height between text and image wrapper.

Comment: Accepted because i finnaly did this solution... Set a min height with !important hack of ie6...

Comment: Well it isnt a solution because it doesnt work well with the !@# IE6...  setting css min-height and using height:auto !important height:2.8em for  the browser regards height as max height:(

Comment: @Parhs Are you sure you are [doing it right?](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/)

Comment: Yes... This works but in this case it doesnt i dont know why...Removing the fixed height ie6 expands ,but when there is no image would be a problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table-cell`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/32NWh/

Comment: thats great but ie6/ie7 is a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

div#leftContent { float : left; position : relative;}
div#rightContent { float : right; position : relative;}
.bottom { position : absolute; bottom : 0; }

</style>
```

This is a rough Stylesheet emulating your skeleton; combined with something like...

```
<div id="leftContent">
<p class="bottom">Your text, as a 'p' element--but it could be any element.</p>
</div>
<div id="rightContent">
<img src="" />
</div>
```

Your `<p>` element (or any element for that matter) would be positioned at the bottom of the left div, wherein you could change the padding/positioning to whatever you'd like; this still allows you to style the image in the adjacent div anyway you'd like.