# Align whole table at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I use the following coding to align the table at the bottom but it can't working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="black">
      <div class="footer">
        <table border="1" bottom="0px">
          <tr>
            <td width="600px" align="right">
              <input type="image"  align="center" id="verify1" src="proceed1.png" disabled="disabled"  width="90" height="90""/>
            </td>
            <td width="500px" align="right">
              <label id = "l2"  style = "color:white;font:normal 20px chalkdust;">NEXT QUESTION</label>
              <div id="sample4" style="float: right;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="image" id="next" src="arrow.png"  disabled="disabled" name="image2" width="80" height="80">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone help this to align at the bottom of page.

Comment: Provide the space (Height and width) for the container div and the float the inner div inside on it.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the bottom alignment in CSS. This will align the div only and not the table. Your table will align because it is within the div.

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should either assign a position absolute or position fixed and bottom 0 and left 0 and width and height to your footer div

[see here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfSQD/)

or google sticky footer in case the above doesnt satisfy your needs

Comment: Consider making a sample of how the OP would apply this and I'll +1 your answer.

Comment: OP refers to the Original Poster of the question.

Comment: OP stands for (I believe) original poster. It's the person who asked the question. Also, please put the important changes to the source in your answer. Just put 4 spaces before your code and it will be formatted nicely.