# Wrap HTML elements bottom to top

Tags: css, word-wrap

Is it possible by HTML / CSS to display a row of elements at the bottom of a container, that wrap upwards if the container gets to small? Like if we would start writing at the bottom of a page and continue above the already written lines.

The elements do not need to be the words of an inline text, a collection of elements like SPAN or DIV placed text-like via `float:left;` for example would do either.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zztRh/  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644178/how-to-make-elements-flow-from-bottom-to-top

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using min-height so the box will expand upwards:

```
#container{
     position:relative;
     width: 300px;
     height: 200px;
     background: #f90;  
}      
#text-container{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 10%;
    background: #f00;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grainne/DD7dG/32/

Comment: That grows the whole block upwards from a given location, but doesn't wrap it's content bottom-up. The idea was that any additional line of text appends to the top rather to the bottom.

Comment: @dronus - you would need to use javascript to get this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. In fact, just having something "bottom-align" is already pretty involved. There are a few "close enough" workarounds, but nothing that's a true "vertical-align: bottom". Examples on websites with such elements have always turned out to be a bunch of JavaScript.

[Basically, many others have tried to deal with this issue before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css)