# How to make elements flow from bottom to top?

Tags: css, alignment

Is there a way in CSS to get elements to behave like the picture on the right?  The order of the elements isn't that important, but the tiles need to occupy the space from the bottom-up rather than top-down as the person resizes the page.

```
  NORMAL         DESIRED
|---------|    |---------|
| A B C D |    | I       |
| E F G H |    | E F G H |
| I       |    | A B C D |
|---------|    |---------|
```

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>

      <style>
        .container {
          margin:10px;
          border:1px solid black;
          float:left;
        }

        .tile {
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          border:1px solid black;
          margin:5px;
          float:left;
          font-size: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 100px;
          vertical-align: middle; 
        }

      </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container-1" class="container">
          <span class="tile">1</span>
          <span class="tile">2</span>
          <span class="tile">3</span>
          <span class="tile">4</span>
          <span class="tile">5</span>
          <span class="tile">6</span>
          <span class="tile">7</span>
          <span class="tile">8</span>
          <span class="tile">9</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do know if you float that to the right while having them `inline-block` will make them order from last to first (in a row though). Maybe this can make some ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Think outside the box:

```
.container, .tile {
    transform:rotate(180deg);         /* Moz and IE10+ */
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);     /* IE9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera/Chrome/Safari */
}
```

Yes, this really works:

```css
.container {
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.tile {
  width:100px;
  height:64px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:5px;
  float:right;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 64px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <span class="tile">1</span>
  <span class="tile">2</span>
  <span class="tile">3</span>
  <span class="tile">4</span>
  <span class="tile">5</span>
  <span class="tile">6</span>
  <span class="tile">7</span>
  <span class="tile">8</span>
  <span class="tile">9</span>
</div>
```

First the container is rotated 180deg to get the desired layout, then `float:right` flips their left/right order, and then the tiles are rotated 180deg again to look as intended.

Comment: @Abernasty erm did you read the CSS comments? Pretty much [every browser](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) except IE<9.

Comment: Worst case it rolls back to default layout - can't imagine this really being *breaking behaviour* in many situations.

Comment: I think (well, it worked for my particular case) that `transform:scaleY(-1)` on the parent container and child elements does the same, without needing the `float:right` bit. Great answer anyways.

Answer (score 16):

There's another way to do this.  You can use CSS3's `flex-wrap` property to achieve the output you're looking for.

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ydWR4/)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of using just CSS would be to employ [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) at specific breakpoints, and to devise 2-4 (depending on how many break points you want, it could be even more) desirable configurations.

Think of the desirable configurations, then you can give your content tiles specific id's to change their styles/widths at each breakpoint. E.g.,

```
<head>

  <style>
    .container {
      margin:10px;
      border:1px solid black;
      float:left;
    }

    .tile {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid black;
      margin:5px;
      float:left;
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      vertical-align: middle; 
    }
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  #tileOne {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #tileTwo {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-1" class="container">
      <span class="tile" id="tileOne">1</span>
      <span class="tile" id="tileTwo">2</span>
      <span class="tile">3</span>
      <span class="tile">4</span>
      <span class="tile">5</span>
      <span class="tile">6</span>
      <span class="tile">7</span>
      <span class="tile">8</span>
      <span class="tile">9</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

This technique would be fully manual, so might not work well for dynamic content unless you also wanted to leverage css-child-selectors, which for backwards compatibility might best be done using jQuery. But because, it's fully manual, it also gives you complete control over the progression.

As with Niels' solution, as presented, this wouldn't work below IE9 because media-query isn't supported.