# More text on bottom line in CSS

Tags: css, text

When a text is on multiple lines, the top lines will have the more text possible and the last line will have the remaining text.

I want to do so the bottom line has the more text and the top line has the remaining text.

I want a text like this :

```
Hello there. How are
you ?
```

but looking like this :

```
Hello
there. How are you ?
```

Is this possible in CSS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make elements flow from bottom to top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644178/how-to-make-elements-flow-from-bottom-to-top)

Comment: Don't think this is possible with current css but I may be wrong as I have never had the need to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap text from bottom to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423951/wrap-text-from-bottom-to-top)