# </ in <script> tag as part of javascript regular expression ending in <

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have some HTML code with inline javascript in a `<script>` tag that contains a regular expression removing superflous whitespace between a `>` and a `<` character as in

```
<script>
[...]
output = output.replace(/>\s*</g, '><');
[...]
</script>
```

This is invalid HTML (e.g., according to PHPs `DOMDocument->loadHTML()`), as the character sequence `</` [ends processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780858/escape-in-script-tag-contents) and is expected to be followed by the rest of the closing tag `script>`.

I have tried to escape the `<` as `&lt;` but then the expression doesn't match anymore (tested in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ezvx9oc/)).

A workaround is to insert something in the regular expression that doesn't actually do anything but separates the `<` from the `/`, such as

```
output = output.replace(/>\s*[<]/g, '><');
```

This works and has the expected behavior, but looks like a terrible hack.

What is the right way to escape `<` before `/` in a js regular expression?

Comment: One of the many reasons not to put code of any significance directly in `script` tags.

Comment: Have a try with: `output = output.replace(/>\s*\</g, '><');`

Comment: @Toto - That won't help

Comment: You don't need to escape anything. You read something wrong. What delimits script is script and nothing else. https://regex101.com/r/t4HQKV/1

Comment: You can create regexp without using regexp literal, e.g.: `const re = new RegExp('>\\s*<'); output = output.replace(re), '><';` -- as you can see this way it does not need slashes at start and end.

Comment: `I have tried to escape the < as &lt;` This should fix the problem as entities are substituted during the html parse process. That's their only purpose.

Comment: @sln - But the content of a `script` element **isn't** HTML, so HTML entities don't work there. (Contrast with, for instance, the content of an `onclick` attribute, which *is* HTML and so `onclick="if (foo &lt; bar) alert(&quot;Hi there&quot;)"` works just fine. :-) )

Comment: If you insist on modifying the regex, use the expanded modifier and just move the characters away from each other `(/ > \s* < /xg` Because `<:space:/` is not a legal start of a closing tag.

Comment: As I said, `&lt;` doesn't work, I tried. Creating the regexp separately is a good suggestion. The `x` modifier is also a neath trick. Thanks!

Comment: @sln: there's no x flag in Javascript. (but this flag is available in XRegExp).

Comment: Just a couple more options for ya. Compile the regex as an object ? `rx = new RegExp(">\\s*<","g");` or if your hung up on the // operators, change the regex to something more reasonable    `output = output.replace(/>\s*(?=<)/g, '>');` but remember that `/>` is also the ending of a self contained tag.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP's `DOMDocument->loadHTML()` thinks the script element ends there, I'm fairly sure it's a bug in `DOMDocument->loadHTML()`. Script elements end with `</script>`, and the content of `script` elements is **not** HTML. [`script` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) have a much more...interesting...content model than that which the spec takes several paragraphs to explain.

Regarding issues with `</`, the spec [only mentions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) dealing with `<!--` and `</script>`, not `</` in general.

But if you have to have inline script (you wouldn't have this problem if the code were in a `.js` file), and you have to load it with something that apparently has a bug, your hack with the character class (`[<]` rather than `<`) isn't bad at all. (I doubt performance is your concern, but if it were, I think we can probably say with a fair bit of assurance that the JavaScript engine's regular expression handler is going to be able to optimize that single-character character class away.)

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer! I discovered the issue with `DOMDocument-loadHTML()`, but what made me think that `</` is an actual problem and not just a bug in that function was this stackexchange question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780858/escape-in-script-tag-contents . I am not concerned about performance at all, rather that someone going through the code in the future will think "Ah, I am going to remove this superfluous charcter class..." :-)

Comment: @cgogolin - Yeah, definitely would need commenting. :-)