# CSS vertically align element to the bottom without height of parent

Tags: css

How can I align element to the bottom of the container without knowing the height?  I want to align the "links" div container to the bottom so it aligns next to the logo text's bottom.  I cannot set a height because users can change the logo size and it could be an image...

Here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">LOGO HERE</a>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
        <a href="#">LINK 2</a>
        <a href="#">LINK 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper { width:100%; -moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
.logo { width:75%;float:left;font-size:100px;}
.links { width:25%;float:left;position:relative;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lejpr/

I should add that I am using Twitter Bootstrap framework so in my case logo and links container are both columns which Bootstrap applies float:left to it.  Since I need this to be responsive, using absolute positioning may not be feasible for me.

Comment: Is this not what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css

Comment: I tried that already and didn't seem to work for me...

Comment: So, in Twitter Bootstrap, .wrapper is a row and .logo and .links are columns (floated blocks)?

Comment: @Marc Audet - exactly!

Comment: If the links and the logo are in separate columns, you won't be able to align the bottoms because the floated blocks/columns do not know which one is taller and hence how to adjust the height.  The only hope is to combine the two columns in the row into a single column and then apply the solution I posted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using inline-blocks and vertical-align property

Here is an alternative to using absolute positioning:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline: 1px solid blue; /* for demo only*/
}
.logo {
    width:74%; /* allow 1% for any white space between logo and links */
    font-size:100px;
    outline: 1px solid blue; /* for demo only*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.links {
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
    outline: 1px solid blue; /* for demo only*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/YbqUz/

Inline blocks are fairly well supported so this may be a viable option.

Depending on how you want the layout to respond to smaller screen widths, you 
may want to set a minimum width for the links block.

Comment: I feel like I did a bad job on my description...I should have added that I am using Twitter Bootstrap and their column system uses floats which will automatically make a container a block level element.  So in my case logo and links container are both columns.

Comment: Are the logo and the links in the same column?

Comment: No, they are separate just like in the html provided. The wrapper is the row, logo is left column and links is right column.

Comment: Thanks!  I will use this as it is the closest possible solution...I would have to override what Bootstrap is applying...

Answer (score 2):

To align the `.links` element vertically to bottom, it should removes from document normal flow. Add a `position: relative` to the `.wrapper` and `position: absolute` to the `.links`.

There's no need to float the `.logo` element; but if it is needed. add `overflow: hidden;` css declaration to its parent. in this case `.wrapper`.

Also, you can set `margin-right` to `.logo` element to display it correctly near the `.links`

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color: gold;
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    font-size:100px;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.links {
    width:25%;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/Lejpr/4/)**

Comment: I understand that this works however I am afraid to use position absolute as I need this to be responsive so when the viewport gets smaller the links container needs to stack below...But if it is position absolute, it won't...Unless I specifically change it with media query...Do you know of any other way other than absolute?

Comment: @Rick Is **[this](http://jsbin.com/iqegex/1)** what you need? This is the TW Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `.links` inside `.logo` and use a combination of relative and absolute positioning.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UyCZA/)

Using the following styles for `.links` will place the div at the bottom of the `.logo` div while filling the remainder 25% of the screen width.

```
.links { 
 width:30%;
 float:left;
 position:absolute; 
 font-size: 14px;
 right: -30%; 
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: But how would this work in terms of responsiveness?  I am using twitter bootstrap to have the columns set...