# Cannot vertical align to the bottom on float

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following html

```
<div class="form-group " id="new_change_form_title">
    <label class="pull-left" for="change_title">Title</label>
    <div dir="auto" class=" pull-left explanation">A short sentence that describe what this is about</div>
    <input class="" dir="auto" id="change_title" name="change[title]" required="required" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

I'd like `.explanation` to be aligned at the bottom as opposed to the result of aligned to top
as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/xQwB5/1/

Changing line-height does help, but if the explanation is long, on small screen it causes problems...

is there a way to align .explanation to be closer to `input` (changing the structure to reach the result is ok)

Comment: isn't it similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css

Comment: not quite since at that question float is not used

Answer (score 0):

Make the height of explanation equal to the height of the label, then put the text inside another div that is positioned absolutely to the bottom. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9JXjK/

```
.valign {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

You also have to make .explanation `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things at play here that need to change in order to acheive the effect you describe:

1. Rather than using floats on the `<label>` and `.explanation`, set them to `display: inline;`
2. Remove the explicit width on `.explanation` - it was causing your text to run to two lines.
3. Now that `.explanation` is set to `display:inline;` the `vertical-align` property will affect it.

[Check out this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQwB5/4/).

I left a red outline around `.explanation` so you could see the element bounds.