# Aligning text "on-the-line" e.g. top, bottom middle

Tags: html, css

Not sure what you actually call the line text is aligned to...

[image]

As you can see the aqua colored '100' there has it's top aligned with 'BRANCH', but I'd like it to align it's bottom with 'BRANCH'. I tried to illustrate that with my image here and the pink overlay.

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h1 class="number">100</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h2 class="description">Branch</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

How would I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Can you post your code / demo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align content of a div to the bottom with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

{vertical-align:baseline}

UPDATE

since you are using 2 divs, you can just do this...

```
div.col-md-4, div.col-md-8 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```