# How to align an image at the bottom-center of the div

Tags: html, css, position

I want to align an image to the **bottom** of a div and also want to **center** it horizontally.

This is what I wanted to accomplish (picture down below), but in my project there's a huge gap below the cow. The picture of the cow is sliced in half, so I want the bottom portion to stick to the bottom of the view port while being responsive.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" >Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main_text">
            <h1>Awh Cow! I got no <span class="yellow">Dribbble</span>.</h1>
            <p>Invite me to Dribbble maybe? Thanks.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="mailto:hi@gauthamsk.com" class="button">Visit Profile</a>

        <div class="cow"></div>

    </div> <!-- end container -->
</div> <!-- end main -->
```

CSS:

```
.cow {
    height: 280px; /* Change this height to change the size of the cow */
    background: url(../images/cow.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Please show your css

Comment: add some fiddle so that easy to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align content of a div to the bottom with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `.main` to have a height of 100%, you need to make sure that there is a height value computed for the containing block.

One way of doing this is to assign `height: 100%` to both the `html` and the `body` tags.

A simple way to position the `.cow` block element at the bottom of `.main` is to use absolute positioning.  First, set `position: relative` to `.main` to set the point of reference for positioning `.cow`.

Apply `position: absolute` to `.cow` and set the bottom offset `bottom: 0` and this will align the bottom edge of `.cow` to the that of `.main`.  Absolute positioning will give a shrink-to-fit width by default, so set `left: 0` and `right: 0` to give `.cow` the full width of `.main`.  This also takes care of any extra width due to any padding or margins added to `.container`.

You may want to assign a minimum height for `.main` to allow for enough space for the text, button and image.  If you shrink the page enough, the absolute positioned element could overlap your text.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.main_text {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.main_text h1 {
  padding-top: 10%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.main_text p {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 30px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  transition: 0.3s background;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  transition: 0.3s background;
}
.cow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.cow img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="main_text">
      <h1>Awh Cow! I got no <span class="yellow">Dribbble</span>.</h1>
      <p>Invite me to Dribbble maybe? Thanks.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="mailto:hi@gauthamsk.com" class="button">Visit Profile</a>
    </div>

    <div class="cow">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Browser support for `flex` is still buggy in some browsers and not backwards compatible, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.  If all you need is horizontal centering if inline or inline-block elements, `text-align: center` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! but I get a horizontal scroll bar when I do this.

Comment: Which element is the horizontal scroll bar on?

Comment: The `.cow` div. I forgot to mention that there is a container inside the maiin div.

Comment: I added the `.container` div, but it does not seem to trigger any scrolling, so something else is going that is not in my snippet.

Comment: Check the "dribbble.html"

Comment: Your `.container` block as left/right padding (20px) and that was causing the scrolling.  I fixed the issue by using left/right offsets to compute the width of `.main` instead of width of 100%. All should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 10):

Use `flexbox` )

```css
.cow {
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="cow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: The best way as of now. I should really get more into flexbox.

Comment: I updated the question with some more code. With flexbox I've centered it and bottom aligned it to the div. But here the .div isn't taking up the height of the `main` div which leaves a gap on the bottom of the img/div.

Comment: Your markup is really bad.. Why do you create `flex` where they are not needed? Okay, it's your choice, but what you don't use `background-image` instead of `<img>` ? In this situation it is a good solution.

Comment: Sorry about the bad markup, I was in a hurry. I have updated the code and re-framed the question in case my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.centerBottom{
  position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HAtpO8aR3njgN73hCAA4?p=preview

Comment: I've edited the question. I've successfully positioned it in the div. But how do I position the div to the bottom?

Comment: The image isn't horizontally centered in the bottom.

Comment: @GauthamSK I was just showing you the bottom position, since that's the problem remaining

Answer (score 1):

we can use css3 transform property as we can use negative percentage property to align the image at bottom.

```css
.centerBottom{
  position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
}
```

```html
 <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="cow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="centerBottom">
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this supported in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/adwc4gwt/

```
    .cow{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
img{
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
```