# Align position absolute element content to bottom with only one element

Tags: html, css, alignment, element, vertical-alignment

I have a position absolute div element with text content inside without any tag, like this:

```
<div class="element">
    This is some content...
</div>


.element{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

I want to align that content to the bottom of the div, but without using more html tags(like [this answer on a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css)), to keep it simple.

How can I achieve this using css only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) like this:

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  This is some content...
</div>
```

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about flex. How about browser support these days?

Comment: Microsoft has already ended support for ancient IE browsers so it's is really good these days :) - http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-ending-support-internet-explorer-8-9-10-next-week

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) appreciated

Comment: you can take a look at this github if you want more compatibility https://github.com/10up/flexibility :)