# How do I place my input in the bottom of his parent?

Tags: css, html

How do I place this input element in the bottom of his div parent and center it?
[image]

Comment: If you want help with your code, show us your [mcve] code, not just a picture. Otherwise the question is likely to be closed as 'too broad' (there's no clear evidence of any attempt being made) or 'off-topic' (as questions must show the minimal relevant code to reproduce the problem you're experiencing). Incidentally, to those answering: we have no details upon which to base answers, guesses - especially guesses with no explanation of what you're doing, how it's being done or what the code means - is of little use to anyone.

Comment: Wait ... you need to give more info is it Illustrator? Photoshop? Paint ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use just CSS for this one you could use `position: absolute;` on the input and `position: relative;` on the parent.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

input {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively you could use flexbox along the lines of:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
parent{
    position: relative;
}

child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why -1? This should work for the thing you ask. Please give more information on what you want and give code as well.

Comment: I down-voted because you attempted to answer a question that presented no code, so we don't know what's going on at all, or what the HTML structure, or any requirements, of the HTML might be. Guesses - especially guesses with no explanation - are of little use to the OP or any future visitors.

Comment: It gives an image, and the css I gave is very generic with 'parent' and 'child'.

Comment: It's a bit mean to attack with downvotes well-intentioned individuals who seek to help someone who has posted a not-very-well-formatted question. You can make a well-reasoned critique of why the answer doesn't work without also downvoting it.

Comment: @Rounin: I don't believe I 'attacked' anyone; I voted in accordance with the '*this answer is not useful*' down-arrow tool-tip, and then explained.

Comment: But the answer is useful.

Comment: This answer works depending on the information that OP gave.