# Onsen UI: button, aligned to bottom

Tags: javascript, css, onsen-ui2

I'm creating application using onsen-ui.

Here is code for my "delete" button

```
<div class='form-well'>
    <br><br>
    <ons-button style="background-color: red;" modifier="large">Delete</ons-button>
</div>
```

All is fine, "Delete" button have proper size & color, but I want it to be aligned at the bottom.

Do library (onsen) have proper "onsenish" way to do this, or I should use generic html patterns (like this [How to align content of a div to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom)) and guess pixels myself?

[image: delete screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css `position` properties like this, i just use button for understanding you can use there `button` `class` or `id`.

```
button {
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
}
```

Comment: Which is basically "no onsen support for it" . Ok.

Answer (score -1):

You can find your answer on if you want to do it with onsen.io

https://onsen.io/blog/auto-style-app-onsen/