# Anki CSS/HTML align vertically to bottom / center / top

Tags: html, css, anki

I am editing the template of an [Anki deck](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1956010956), which uses HTML and CSS. What I would like to do here is on the front side, vertically aligning the Japanese character to the middle and the hint to the bottom. I tried manually spacing everything with `<br>`, but then it doesn't work in different resolution windows (and is just a dirty solution) [Front example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCRtU.png).

On the back side I would like to make the stroke diagram always snap to the top, the Japanese character with keyword and mnemonic in the middle, and the rest on the bottom. If I  tried spacing this with `<br>` I would get the same problem as on the front page, plus the mnemonic is sometimes 1 line, but can also be 5+ lines so it would have to be aligned dynamically to work even if the window size was always the same [Back example with arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlA2C.png).

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom#) question which seems to somewhat answer my question, but as I know practically nothing about CSS/HTML I don't know how to apply it in my case. If you could help me I would greatly appreciate it as I spend a lot of time with this deck and it keeps annoying me, I would also share the improved version for other people to use.

Here is the code for the front

```html
<div class="front" lang="ja">


<span class="large japanese">{{kanji}}</span>

<br>
<hr>


{{hint:Memory palace}}
```

back

```html
<div class="back" lang="ja">
{{strokeDiagram}}<br> <br>
 <hr> 
 <span class="medium"><a href="http://jisho.org/kanji/details/{{kanji}}">{{keyword}}</a></span>
 <br/><br/>
 
<span class="large japanese">{{kanji}}</span>

<br> 
<span class="medium">{{myStory}}</span>  <br><hr> 
<span class="tiny"> Memory palace: {{Memory palace}}</span>


<span class="tiny"> &nbsp; Frame: {{frameNoV6}} &nbsp; Strokes: {{strokeCount}} &nbsp; &mdash; &nbsp; Jouyou Grade: {{jouYou}} &nbsp; JLPT: {{jlpt}}</span><br/>

<!-- Uncomment for Heisig Story          
<hr>
 <span class="medium">{{heisigStory}}</span>
 {{#heisigComment}}<br/><br/><span class="small">{{heisigComment}}</span>{{/heisigComment}}
-->

<!-- Uncomment for koohi Story
<hr/>
 <span class="medium">{{koohiiStory1}}</span>

-->

<hr/>
 <br> <br>
<!-- Uncomment for On-Yomi and Kun-Yomi
 <span class="small">On-Yomi: <span class="medium japanese">{{onYomi}}</span> &nbsp; Kun-Yomi: <span class="medium japanese">{{kunYomi}}</span></span><br/>
-->
<span class="tiny"><a href="http://kanji.koohii.com/study/kanji/{{kanji}}">Constituents:</a> {{constituent}}</span><br/><br/>
 {{#readingExamples}}<span class="tiny">Examples: <span class="japanese">{{readingExamples}}</span></span>{{/readingExamples}}
</div>
```

and the styling,

```css
div.front, div.back {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px; /* line height is based on this size in Anki for some reason, so start with the smallest size used */

}


span.tiny {font-size: 16px;}
span.small {font-size: 24px;}
span.medium {font-size: 32px;}
span.large {font-size: 96px;}
span.italic {font-style: italic;}

.win .japanese {font-family: "Meiryo", "MS Mincho";}
.mac .japanese {font-family: "Hiragino Mincho Pro";}
.linux .japanese {font-family: "Kochi Mincho";}
.mobile .japanese {font-family: "Motoya L Cedar", "Motoya L Maru", "DroidSansJapanese", "Hiragino Mincho ProN";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Front

```css
div.front,
div.back {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* line height is based on this size in Anki for some reason, so start with the smallest size used */
}

span.tiny {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.small {
  font-size: 24px;
}

span.medium {
  font-size: 32px;
}

span.large {
  font-size: 96px;
}

span.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.win .japanese {
  font-family: "Meiryo", "MS Mincho";
}

.mac .japanese {
  font-family: "Hiragino Mincho Pro";
}

.linux .japanese {
  font-family: "Kochi Mincho";
}

.mobile .japanese {
  font-family: "Motoya L Cedar", "Motoya L Maru", "DroidSansJapanese", "Hiragino Mincho ProN";
}


/* Positional */

.bottom {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* I want a better way to do the below! */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.top {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="front" lang="ja">


  <span class="large japanese center">{{kanji}}</span>

  <hr>


  <span class="bottom">{{hint:Memory palace}}</span>
```

Note that the `<hr>` is unstyled.

### Back

```css
div.front,
div.back {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* line height is based on this size in Anki for some reason, so start with the smallest size used */
}

span.tiny {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.small {
  font-size: 24px;
}

span.medium {
  font-size: 32px;
}

span.large {
  font-size: 96px;
}

span.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.win .japanese {
  font-family: "Meiryo", "MS Mincho";
}

.mac .japanese {
  font-family: "Hiragino Mincho Pro";
}

.linux .japanese {
  font-family: "Kochi Mincho";
}

.mobile .japanese {
  font-family: "Motoya L Cedar", "Motoya L Maru", "DroidSansJapanese", "Hiragino Mincho ProN";
}


/* Positional */

.bottom {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* I want a better way to do the below! */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.top {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="back" lang="ja">
  <div class="top">{{strokeDiagram}}</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="center"><span class="medium"><a href="http://jisho.org/kanji/details/{{kanji}}">{{keyword}}</a></span>

    <span class="large japanese">{{kanji}}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <span class="medium">{{myStory}}</span> <br>
    <hr>
    <span class="tiny"> Memory palace: {{Memory palace}}</span>


    <span class="tiny"> &nbsp; Frame: {{frameNoV6}} &nbsp; Strokes: {{strokeCount}} &nbsp; &mdash; &nbsp; Jouyou Grade: {{jouYou}} &nbsp; JLPT: {{jlpt}}</span><br/>

    <!-- Uncomment for Heisig Story          
<hr>
 <span class="medium">{{heisigStory}}</span>
 {{#heisigComment}}<br/><br/><span class="small">{{heisigComment}}</span>{{/heisigComment}}
-->

    <!-- Uncomment for koohi Story
<hr/>
 <span class="medium">{{koohiiStory1}}</span>

-->

    <hr/>
    <br> <br>
    <!-- Uncomment for On-Yomi and Kun-Yomi
 <span class="small">On-Yomi: <span class="medium japanese">{{onYomi}}</span> &nbsp; Kun-Yomi: <span class="medium japanese">{{kunYomi}}</span></span><br/>
-->
    <span class="tiny"><a href="http://kanji.koohii.com/study/kanji/{{kanji}}">Constituents:</a> {{constituent}}</span><br/><br/> {{#readingExamples}}
    <span class="tiny">Examples: <span class="japanese">{{readingExamples}}</span></span>{{/readingExamples}}
  </div>
</div>
```

One problem with this technique is that, if there is insufficient space, they will draw over each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the hint is at the bottom which is nice, I just can't get the Japanese to appear at the top with it also centered in the middle horizontally .Also feel free to change the HTML if it helps (if I understood you correctly)

Comment: @AfroSamuraí Are you talking about the back? I only did the front. Currently I'm on a device that doesn't support Stack Snippets or Anki, so I can't test making a new back.

Comment: oh that's my bad, I may have worded it poorly in my question. The hint being at the bottom is perfect, I just wanted the Japanese character to stay at the top or in the middle (vertically). I figured out from your answer that you could probably do `position: absolute;
  top: 0` as well and make another class or something

Comment: @AfroSamuraí I thought it did stay in the middle... Staying at the top is easy; it's the same as bottom but changed in the way you'd expect. I'll see what I can do about it in between 8 and 14 hours' time.

Comment: @AfroSamuraí Is this OK?