# centre align container div and align text to bottom of div

Tags: html, css

**What I am trying to achieve:** center a container div (that contains two divs) and in 2nd div, bottom align text

- in my 1st div, it's a picture
- in my 2nd div, two paragraphs of text

  ```
                ———————-----
                |          |
                |          |       column2
                | column1  |  -———————-------
                | picture  |  | Paragraph   |
                |          |  ———————--------
                |          |   ———————————------------------
                |          |  | a paragraph of text        |
                |          |  | of text of text of text of |
                ——————----——   ———————----------------------
  ```

**My issue:**

- I can't align my two paragraphs to be at the bottom. They are at the top.
- My container div isn't aligned to the center too

**Currently they look like this:**

```
    ———————-----    -———————-------
   |    picture  |  | Paragraph   |
   |             |  ———————--------
   |             |   ———————————------------------
   |             |  | a paragraph of text        |
   |             |  | of text of text of text of |
   |             |   ———————----------------------
   |             |
   |             |
   |             |
    ------------
```

My current code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img column1">
      <img id="img" src="https://animage.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment column2">
      <p>a paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



.column1, .column2{
  width:300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
#img{
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 600px;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: give positioning to that text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align content of a div to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{display:flex;}
.column1, .column2{
  width:200px;
 
  margin: 10px;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  flex-direction:column;
  
}
.column2{

justify-content:flex-end;
display:flex;
}
#img{
  max-width: 100%;

}
p{ margin:0;}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img column1">
      <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    </div>
    <div class="comment column2">
      <p>a paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
       <p>another paragraph</p> <p>another paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! however, there's a little gap between img and the bottom border. why so? i don't see any padding in your column2 code :?

Answer (score 5):

Changing your align method to Flex, you could achieve this easy, take a look bellow

Just removed `float: left` on the column elements and added `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end` at the container.

```css
.column1, .column2{
  width:300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#img{
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 600px;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img column1">
      <img id="img" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
    </div>
    <div class="comment column2">
      <p>a paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Maybe explain why you use that method. +1

Comment: @KwokWenJian but this picture show what you expected on the question, align the text at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and probably nicest solutions for this is using a "flexible box layout". In the snippet below I've layed out an example you could use. I recommend reading more on `flexbox`, since it can most definitely help you again with future layout issues:

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[CSS Flexible Box Layout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
   
  /* just for presentation */
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column--picture{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  /* up to you */
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

.column--picture img{
  /*
   make sure to limit the size of the image,
   or make `.column--picture` to not show
   overflow content
  */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.column--wrapper{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  
  /* just for presentation */
  max-width: 400px;
}

.row{
  /* just for presentation */
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column--picture">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458966480358-a0ac42de0a7a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI2ODUxfQ&s=b92b03976bc401ad70337cfd39e9ed95" alt="green leaf tree on shore">
  </div>
  <div class="column column--wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Stop floating and start flexing.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>Turkey beef biltong, sausage ball tip pork loin pork chop corned beef boudin ground round salami pancetta flank filet mignon sirloin.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! how do i keep the photo flex end as well? I tried to set img width to 100% and it shot upwards and is stuck to the ceiling :/ i did this:   display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
https://imgur.com/a/oM6jHx7

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve this. If you are trying to be compatible with older browser (eg IE 10 ), This may not work. Flexbox is the better way to align items.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container img {
     height: 180px;
}

.container .column2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img column1">
      <img 
  id="img"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/58/Penny_test.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment column2">
      <p>a paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it works if "another paragraph" was short. but if it was a sentence long, it runs on and pushes the image to the left :/

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your CSS.

```
.column1, .column2 {
  width:300px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
p {    
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;    
}
```

Please see [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/DharaSumitPatel/b3w4jfa1/5/) for your solution.