# How to wrap parent block around shifted child block?

Tags: html, css

How to shift a child block?
How to shift the blue block so that it stretches the parent block?

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.preMain {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="preMain">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Current Result]

---

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your child block has `position: absolute;` meaning it no longer affects the parent div. If you want to shift the child block down but still have it affect the parent block you need to change the `position` of the child. Try something like this:

```
.main {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.preMain {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 350px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Admittedly not a perfect solution but you should be able to achieve the result you're looking for.

Alternately, look to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using position: absolute, which allows to use bottom and left to position the element correctly.

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.preMain {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="preMain">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think they wanted the parent to stretch down to wrap around the child at a set position. Setting bottom and left means the child is not in the desired position and is instead still inside the confines of the parent.