# How can I make a relative object always be on the bottom of a div [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

So I'm building cards for products but because some of the height of the product is bigger the `See offer` button doesn't go to the bottom.

Here are some images as an example of my problem

[image]

I changed the background to blue so it's better to visualize the problem.
As you can see in the first card the title is a bit shorter making the button not be at the bottom like in image 2.

Here is my code

```css
<style>body {
  position: relative;
}

.see_offer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.see_offer span {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 39.93px);
  top: calc(50% - 9.2px);
  color: white;
}

.trustpilot-widget {
  margin-top: 4em;
}

.main-body {
  max-width: 1270px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-content .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.page-content .first-section .carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.page-content .first-section .carousel-cell img {
  width: 100%;
}

.page-content .second-section {
  padding-top: 131px;
}

.page-content .second-section .title {
  display: flex;
}

.page-content .second-section .title span {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 64px;
  letter-spacing: 0.21em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.page-content .second-section .title span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #1D1D25;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 96%;
  top: 76px;
  left: 0;
}

.second-section .products {
  padding-top: 115px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.second-section .products .box {
  max-width: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin-bottom: 62px;
}

.second-section .products .box .image {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  min-height: 157px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second-section .products .box .image img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.second-section .products .box .names {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.second-section .products .box .star {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.second-section .products .box .price {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  color: #1D1D25;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second-section .products .box .price span:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  vertical-align: super;
}

.second-section .products .box .price span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.second-section .pagination-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.second-section .pagination-container span,
.second-section .pagination-container a {
  color: #1D1D25;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-width: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.second-section .pagination-container .active .current {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1D1D25;
}

.second-section .pagination-container li .page-link {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
}

.second-section .pagination-container .current.prev,
.second-section .pagination-container .current.next,
.second-section .pagination-container .page-link.prev,
.second-section .pagination-container .page-link.next {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-width: 0;
}

.second-section .pagination-container .prev-image {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.second-section .pagination-container .next-image {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.page-content .third-section {
  padding-top: 90px;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F9FBFC;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}

.page-content .third-section .container {
  display: block;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .text .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1D1D25;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .text .sub-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 119px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar input {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 22px;
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-width: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar input::placeholder {
  color: #B7B6B6;
}

.page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar a {
  background-color: #F81732;
  color: white;
  padding: 22px 32px;
  border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (min-width: 1360px) {
  .second-section .products {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .page-content {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .third-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .page-content {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('../assets/images/frame.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.2;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 300px 180px;
    background-position: top right;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .left {
    order: 1;
    padding-left: 9%;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .left .first-text {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .left .second-text {
    padding-left: 0em;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .left .third-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .left .btn-red {
    display: none;
  }
  .page-content .first-section .container .right img {
    display: none;
  }
  .page-content .second-section {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .second-section .products {
    padding-top: 35px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box {
    width: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .title span {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .title span::after {
    top: 60px;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .left {
    order: 1;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .left img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .page-content .second-section .right {
    padding-right: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .image {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .image img {
    max-width: 170px;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .names {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .star {
    padding-bottom: 11px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .price {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .price span:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
  .second-section .products .box .price span:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 33px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .text {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .text .title {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .text .sub-title {
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar input {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 13px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-width: 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .subscribe-bar a {
    padding: 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .board-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .page-content .third-section .container .board-container .board {
    width: auto;
    margin: 15px 8px;
  }
}

.user-info,
.user-info .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .user-info .text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #55555b;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 14px;
}

</style><!-- Common.js code --><style>body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  /* make scrollbar transparent */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Segoe UI.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Italic";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Segoe UI Italic"), url("../assets/fonts/Segoe UI Italic.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Segoe UI Bold"), url("../assets/fonts/Segoe UI Bold.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Bold Italic";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Segoe UI Bold Italic"), url("../assets/fonts/Segoe UI Bold Italic.woff") format("woff");
}


</style>
```

```html
<section class="second-section">
  <div class="title">
    <span>Popular</span>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
    <div class="box" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <div class="image">
        <img :src="product.image" />
      </div>
      <div class="names">
        Soy Protein 90 (Isolate) Unflavoured 2kg
      </div>
      <!--
              <div class="star">
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-gray" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              -->
      <div class="price">
        <span>GBP</span><span>29.99</span>
      </div>
      <a :href="product.url">
        <div class="see_offer">
          <span>SEE OFEER</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <div class="image">
        <img :src="product.image" />
      </div>
      <div class="names">
        Whey Protein 80 (Concentrate) Unflavoured 500g
      </div>
      <!--
              <div class="star">
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-yellow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star color-gray" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              -->
      <div class="price">
        <span>GBP</span><span>29.99</span>
      </div>
      <a :href="product.url">
        <div class="see_offer">
          <span>SEE OFEER</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagination-container" class="pagination-container"></div>
</section>
```

So my question is there any way I could make it always 0px from the bottom of the div?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777362/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the parent element `position: relative` and the child element `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` should do the trick.