# Button align buttom in materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to bottom align a materialize CSS button.

Please see my current situation below:-

[image]

My HTML form button looks like this:-

```
<div class="col s1">
<a id="btn" style="vertical-align: bottom; display: inline-block; position: bottom;" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-3">Submit</a>
</div>
```

what should I do to bottom align it in the same row?

Comment: just fyi, _position: bottom_ is invalid style

Comment: We need more codes, sometimes another elements tries to break something or they're the problem solve so give us more codes please and check this question please maybe helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
#element {
position: absolute;
top: 3%;}
```

test and adjust to by yourself