# how can I place images, from a search result. in columns at the bottom of the web page. as mine are currently in a row going straight down the middle?

Tags: image, url

how can I place images, from a search result. in columns  at the bottom of the web page. as mine are currently in a row going straight down the middle? I am using css

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 5px solid lightyellow;
  box-shadow: #rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

Answer (score 0):

**Strategy 1**: Wrap your result into a `div` and set its `position` attribute.

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>Some text more or less</p>

<div class="content">
  
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/cccccc/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/cccccc/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/cccccc/fff" />
  
</div>
```

How to align content at the bottom of a page:
[explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom)

**Strategy 2**: Use flexbox to align items.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>Some text more or less</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

How to use flexgrid for responsive image grid:
[read this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp)