# How to align grid columns to the baseline while keeping them stretched?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with two columns. The second column has a larger font size:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.text1 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 3.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text1">text1</div>
  <div class="text2">text2</div>
</div>
```

I wanted to align the texts to the baseline so I added `align-items: baseline;` to `.container` and this happened:

[image]

The texts are aligned correctly but the black background doesn't take the whole grid block. How can I keep the text1 container stretched while aligning its content to baseline?

I've tried these but none of them worked:

1. adding `height: 100%` to `.text1`
2. adding `align-self: stretch` and `align-content: baseline` to `.text1`
3. a wrapper `div` for the background and a `span` for the content and setting `align-self: baseline` for the `span`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to align text item by flex:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.text1 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: last baseline;
}

.text2 {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="text1">text1</div>
    <div class="text2">text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The one tweak you might make to this is setting `.text2 { align-self: baseline; }` so that the text baselines are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a table, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom) might point you in the correct direction.

If you don't mind using `display: table`, you can use the `vertical-align` property, as shown here.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.text1 {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 3.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text1">text1</div>
  <div class="text2">text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. `vertical-align: bottom` is a little different than `align-items: baseline` as it doesn't take `line-height` into account. Also in your code snippet the texts aren't aligned correctly. So it doesn't suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I used `align-items:self-end` , `display:flex` and `line-height` attributes  to align the texts same level.

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax( max-content, 0px));
 grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.text1 {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 align-items:self-end;
 display:flex;
 height:100px;
 padding:25px 25px 0px 25px;
 line-height:0.9;

}
.text2 {
 color: #000;
 display: flex;
 align-items:self-end;
 font-size: 3.25rem;
 line-height: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text1">text1</div>
 <div class="text2">text2</div> 
</div>
```