# Layout form fields without tables

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a very simple HTML layout I'm trying to implement. It is something like this:

```
A Label:         [Input                ]
Another Label:   [Input                ]
The Last Label:  [Input                ]
```

In the past, I'd just go ahead and use a table for this. Otherwise, it's a pain getting the input controls to line up correctly.

Can anyone suggest a simple and reliable way to implement this layout without using a table?

Thanks.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519234/why-use-definition-lists-dl-dd-dt-tags-for-html-forms-instead-of-tables][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519234/why-use-definition-lists-dl-dd-dt-tags-for-html-forms-instead-of-tables

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: inline-block`

```
<style type="text/css">
  label { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }
  ul { list-style: none; }
</style>

<ul>
  <li><label for="input1">A Label:</label> <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"></li>
  <li><label for="input2">Another Label:</label> <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"></li>
  <li><label for="input3">The Last Label:</label> <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3"></li>
</ul>
```

However, in order for this to line up vertically, you either have to wrap the label-input pairs in another tag (such as `<li>` or `<div>`) or put linebreaks after the inputs.

Comment: No, you don't need to wrap them with additional elements just to get them to line up vertically. Especially if you give the labels a fixed width.

Comment: @DanMan True, I guess I'm just not a big fan of floats

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
  label { width: 200px; float:left; clear:left; } 
  input { float:left;} 
</style>
<form>
  <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
</form>
```

With the added benefit that, if the horizontal space isn't sufficient, the inputs will wrap below the labels.

http://jsbin.com/anuziq (narrow down your browser window)

If you don't actually want them to wrap around, I suggest this approach:

```
<style>
   label { white-space: nowrap; } 
   span { width: 200px; display: inline-block; }
</style>
<form>
  <label>
      <span>Full Name:</span>
      <input type="text" name="fullname">
  </label>
  <label>
      <span>Email Address:</span>
      <input type="text" name="email">
  </label>
</form>
```

From my experience, structuring the HTML like that usually allows for any layout you can possibly think of. Want the inputs always below the label? Use `display:block` on the `span` elements. Want the text to the right of the `input`? Just use `float:right` on the `span`.

Bonus here is that you don't need the `for` and `id` attributes to connect the label with the input. They're only really necessary, if you can't put the label right next to the input, like in 2 separate table cells.