# Can I put anything inside DL/DT/DDs?

Tags: html, html-lists

can I use definition lists just like unordered/ordered lists?

I mean insert DIVs any anything I want inside DT or DD?

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    ...
  </dt>
  <dd>
    ...
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Do any browsers, or search engines complain?

Comment: Do search engines complain? I think they only complain when we whip them but don't feed them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Updated answer based on comments:**

This was originally answered in 2011 for HTML 4, but the answer is different for HTML5:

> **`dt`**
> Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or heading content descendants.
> **`dd`**
> Flow content.

- [dt element reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) on W3C
- [dd element reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dd-element) on W3C

**Original answer:**

`DT` elements should contain [inline content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Inline_elements).
`DD` elements should contain [block-level content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements).

> Definition lists vary only slightly
> from other types of lists in that list
> items consist of two parts: a term and
> a description. The term is given by
> the DT element and is restricted to
> inline content. The description is
> given with a DD element that contains
> block-level content.
>
> *Source:* [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)

This question is also an interesting read: [Why use definition lists (DL,DD,DT) tags for HTML forms instead of tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519234/why-use-definition-lists-dl-dd-dt-tags-for-html-forms-instead-of-tables)

Comment: How come you don't use the W3C documentation? It is doctype-related. For instance, HTML 4.01: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3

Comment: @Jared Farrish: You're right and the original info was wrong! Updated.

Comment: No problem; always best to go to the source. :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I know - more often than not it's sites like About and W3Schools that rank higher in search results despite containing inaccurate information. Damn you Google! ;) All updated with reputable sources now.

Comment: The answer is not valid anymore as you can have flow content in both <dt> and <dd> elements according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element

Answer (score 12):

Inside a `DL` you can only put `DT` and `DD` tags. A `DT` tag is an [inline tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-DT), so you should not put block elements in it. A `DD` tag can contain basically anything you want, it's a flow content tag.

Answer (score 6):

As of December 2017 according to HTML 5.2 Specification, you can now add a single nested `<div>` tag inside a `<dl>` tag, I assume for styling purposes:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element

> **Content model:**
>
> Either: Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more dt elements followed by one or more dd elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.
>
> Or: One or more div elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.