# Html semantics for displaying label and content from database

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display few values (which i am fetching from database) along with its label.
The layout is like

Label 1

Value 1

Label 2

Value 2 + (some static text)

Label 3

Value 3(multiple lines)

Label 4

Value 4 (It's actually a list)

Currently I am using two `span` tag enclosed inside `p` tag for displaying label and its value.

My question is what is the best way to do this which is semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best is always subject to discussions, and depends on the data itself. One usual option, that matches most cases, is to use [definition lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl):

```
<dl>
  <dt>Label 1</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  ..
</dl>
```

Comment: In case of Value 4 i need to use <ol> or <ul>. can i use <ol> and <ul> inside <dd> tag

Comment: In case of value 3 can i use <p> tag inside <dd>

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392513/can-i-put-anything-inside-dl-dt-dds

Comment: As @hugoderhungrige said, inside `<dd>` you can use (basically) any HTML, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little on the data you're trying to display. You could use a definition list, if your content is something like a glossary.

```
<dl>
  <dt>AA</dt>
  <dd>Auto Answer (Modem)</dd>
  <dt>AARP</dt>
  <dd>Appletalk Address Resolution Protocol</dd>
  ...
</dl>
```

Otherwise using divs and spans with appropriate semantic class-names should be the way to go. Depending on the context I might not use the p-tag, if this is not embedded in some kind of running text.

Comment: As a side-note: Although the definition list is narrow in its intended purpose, I personally wouldn't mind if some uses them for other data as well. The important point to me is, that you can quickly see what kind of content is being handled whether you do this with class-names or html tags.

Comment: Hi, mind looking my comment on the below answer and help me