# Full length row in dl

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I have a dl list configured as horizontal. I would like to visualize a full length row inside a `<dl>` tag.

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Label 1</dt>
  <dd>Text 1</dd>
  <dt>how to display a full length text?</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Label 2</dt>
  <dd>Text 2</dd>
</dl>
```

I would like to obtain something like this:

[image: Full row between tags]

Comment: [Can I put anything inside DL/DT/DDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392513/can-i-put-anything-inside-dl-dt-dds)

Comment: Thanks @tgogos. 
I have already seen that link. In my opinion, that answer doesn't give information that I don't have, or better it doesn't respond to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Check Demo [here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/oWJXBN?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
 <dt>Label 1</dt>
 <dd>Text 1</dd>
 <dt class="fullWidth"> 26 Lakeshore View, Sentosa Cove, Singapore 26 Lakeshore View, Sentosa Cove.</dt>
 <dd></dd>
 <dt>Label 2</dt>
 <dd>Text 2</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
.fullWidth + dd {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: unset;
}
.dl-horizontal dt.fullWidth {
    width: 100%;
    text-overflow: unset;
    white-space: initial;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why but unfortunately with my configuration this snippet doesn't work

Comment: @Cyr Make an demo on Codepen or jsfiddle to understand where is the problem.

Comment: I have changed the `dt` block adding a `!important` value in width parameter: `.dl-horizontal dt.fullWidth { width: 100% !important ; text-overflow: unset; white-space: initial; text-align: left; }` in this way my configuration works!

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AshokBasarakod/vw1d5z5j/) may solve your problem.

Codes are as followed.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <dt class="col-xs-6">Label 1</dt>
      <dd class="col-xs-6">Text 1</dd>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <dd class="col-md-12">I guess this is what you are looking. This may help you. in bootstrap each row is devided into 12 columns. For more information you can check bootstrap grid system.  </dd>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <dt class="col-xs-6">Label 2</dt>
      <dd class="col-xs-6">Text 2</dd>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <dd class="col-md-12">Defination of lable2 Text2. This contains the defination.</dd>
</div>
  </dl>
</div>
```

You need to add [bootstrap.js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js) and [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) files.

Comment: I know that you can't use `<div>` into `<dl>` section because only `<dt>` and `<dd>` are allowed, as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl)

Comment: @Cyr Without <div> you can achieve the same. I have updated the fiddle, you can try.